# Difference between Proxmark3 rdv4 & Proxmark3 evo

Tags: nfc, rfid

I am an advanced beginner in RFID/NFC reversing / hacking. For now, I have a mifare reader and I want to buy a better reader to able to perform advanced stuffs on both HF and LF (especially emulation and cloning).

So I read multiple website about Proxmark3 evo and Proxmark3 rdv4. I am wondering what are the differences in term of what I can do with the rdv4 that I can not do with the Evo version ?

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: https://lab401.com/collections/hardware/products/rfid-pentester-pack check the page